# Invalid PostCSS plugin error while deploying next js site to vercel

Tags: next.js, postcss, vercel

I am trying to deploy a site built with next js ( and with tailwindcss) to vercel.But I keep getting this '' Invalid PostCSS Plugin" error".

[Error shown in the vercel log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hyc3V.png)

Works completely fine locally.
I'm trying to deploy the site by importing from github.

My postcss.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
       plugins: ['postcss-import', 'tailwindcss', 'autoprefixer']
    }
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "community-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "website for Education and Sports Club",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.4",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "cosmicjs": "^3.2.48",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "next": "^9.4.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.4.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:tailwind": "postcss styles/tailwind.css -o styles/tailwind.generated.css",
    "watch:tailwind": "postcss -w styles/tailwind.css -o styles/tailwind.generated.css",
    "start": "run-p watch:tailwind start:next",
    "start:next": "next start",
    "dev": "next",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:tailwind",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "author": "Salvator",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm a `yarn.lock` or a `package.lock` is not checked in to the repository, if it is delete and confirm if that solves the issue.

Comment: Do you mean package-lock.json file? I have kept it in .gitignore.

Comment: correct `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`